# configure :error: No usable version of sed found:

Tags: makefile

I did ./configure to make a makefile

but it ran into an error:  configure :error: No usable version of sed found:

I then typed which see

it shows /usr/bin/sed.

so, what's wrong? why can't ./configure find sed?

Comment: That error doesn't say it didn't find `sed`. It says it couldn't find a usable version of `sed`. That being said I would be very surprised if you had `sed` but configure couldn't use it for some reason unless you have a very old or odd `sed` version. What does `sed --version` (or `-v` or whatever) say? What does the bit in `config.log` about trying to test `sed` say configure did and what failed?

Answer (score 7):

I happened to have this problem on my mac. This is because OS X uses an old version of sed. Installing gnu-sed by `brew install gnu-sed` and `alias gsed=sed` solved this problem. You may install gnu-sed with other method.